# Join tables in Spotfire in a third new table

Tags: join, spotfire

I have two data tables `tab1` and `tab2` that I want to join.
I know how to do it with the insert columns property, however it is not what i really need. I want the result to be stored in a third new table `tab3`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service - You need to actually attempt to solve your problem before asking for help.

Comment: if you look into spotfire join videos and existing tutorials you would find one solution that comes agains and again, which is : go to the insert tab and click on columns and then look for the other table. This manipulation adds columns from tab2 into tab1, in other words, your tab1 is modified (more columns) which is normal, but this is not the result i need.

Comment: Improve orthography.

Answer (score 1):

Add new data table, add from current analysis (scroll down). Select table 1. Name it table 3. Now insert columns to table 3 from table 2. At the end of this you will have 3 tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am aware of this work around too. the reason i want to be able to generate a third table is that i am constantly modifying (sometimes replacing) one of the tables tab1 and tab2 as a result the join is not updated dynamically. if there was a way to generate the join table without having to duplicated that would have been less struggle for me.

Comment: On newer versions of spotfire, you can use the data icon to see a graphical view of the datatable lineage and modify joins, rows, transformations etc right from the datatable. This may help you. Also, you could generate the join in TERR and dump it out to a table so you dont have to duplicate. Most times, haveing an extra datatable is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

you can Add New Data Table From... Current Analysis>>[your existing data table] to create a reference or "virtual" table. any structural changes made to your referenced (original) table will propogate to the referenced (new) one.